# First foundamental theorem of welfare economics

Tags: microeconomics

Why the First foundamental theorem of welfare economics requires local nonsatiation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first foundamental theorem of welfare economics states that under locally-non satiated preferences, and if $(x^{\ast},y^{\ast},p)$ is a price equilibrium with transfers, then, the allocation $(x^{\ast},y^{\ast})$ is Pareto optimal. Note that a Walrasian equilibrium is a special case of a price equilibrium with  transfers.

Few remarks:

$i)$ $x^{\ast}=(x^{\ast}_1,~x_2^{\ast},...,~x_i^{\ast},...,x_I^{\ast})$ is a list of optimal FEASIBLE consumption bundles (those maximizing utility for all $i=1,2,...,I$ consumers). Each $x_i^{\ast}$ optimal consumption bundle describes the set of optimal $L$ commodities consumed, that is, $~x_i^{\ast}=(x_{1i},x_{2i},...,x_{Li})$. We basically have $L$ commodities.
Also, $y^{\ast}=(y^{\ast}_1,~y_2^{\ast},...,y_j^{\ast},...,y_J^{\ast})$ is a list of optimal FEASIBLE production plans maximizing profits for all $j=1,2,...,J$ firms. Each $y^{\ast}_j$ optimal production plan is of size $L$, i.e., $y^{\ast}_j(y_{1j},y_{2j},...,y_{Lj})$. The idea is that each commodity can be either consumed or used as input.
Finally, $p$ is the price vector of the $L$ commodities.

$ii)$A price equilibrium with transfers is an allocation $(x^{\ast},y^{\ast})$ and a price vector $p=(p_1,p_2,...,p_L)$ with an assignment of wealth levels $(w_1,w_2,...,w_I)$, one for each consumer, such that all firms maximize profits, all consumers maximize their well-being and all markets clear.

Why the theorem you asked requires local non-satiation?
Because, if $(x^{\ast},y^{\ast})$ is Pareto optimal, it cannot be any other feasible allocation that Pareto dominates it.
Indeed, $x^{\ast}$ contains a list of the best consumption bundles that consumers can afford. It must that, if there is an $x_i \succ_i x_i^{\ast}$, then $p \cdot x_i > w_i$, and so $x_i$ must be non affordable.
Also, if $x_i \succsim_i x_i^{\ast} $, then it must be $p \cdot x_i \ge w_i$. Suppose that $p \cdot x_i \ge w_i$ is false, and so there is an $x_i \succsim
_i x_i^{\ast}$ such that $p \cdot x_i < w_i$. If local nonsatiation holds, there must be another bundle, say $x_i^{'}$ that is extremely closed to $x_i$ such that $x_i^{'} \succ x_i$ and still $p \cdot x_i^{'}< w_i$. By transitivity, it must be that $x_i^{'} \succ x_i^{\ast}$. But this is a contraddiction beacuse it cannot be another bundle strictly preferred to $x_i^{\ast}$. So, $x_i^{'} \succ x_i^{\ast}$ is NOT POSSIBLE, and local non satiation rules out this possibility.